# Moq override previous setup?

Tags: c#, parameters, nunit, overriding, moq

Hi I am trying to set an mock of a class's method with two possible input. When i check output only the last set up return expected output. The first one did not. Any help is much appreciated.

```
[Test]
public void ClimbOnceTwoNeighbour_Sample()
{
    stateConverter = new Mock<StateConverter>();

    solution = new Mock<Solution>();
    state = new Mock<State>();

    var neightbourSolution1 = new Mock<Solution>();
    var neighbourState1 = new Mock<State>();
    var neightbourSolution2 = new Mock<Solution>();
    var neighbourState2 = new Mock<State>();

    stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(neightbourSolution1.Object, It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState1.Object);
    stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(neightbourSolution2.Object, It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState2.Object);

    var state1 = stateConverter.Object.FromSolution(neightbourSolution1.Object, state.Object);//return null ????
    var state2 = stateConverter.Object.FromSolution(neightbourSolution2.Object, state.Object);//return neighbourState2.Object)


    Assert.AreEqual(neighbourState2.Object, state2);//pass test here
    Assert.AreEqual(neighbourState1.Object, state1);//fail here due to null is returned from previous statement

}
```

Comment: I suggest you split this test up into two different tests, one for each type of input. Simplicity is key with unit tests.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. This is not a main part i want to test, however this snippet code effect the outcome of that test. :-(

Comment: I have found the cause issue however I still not sure how to fix it. If Solution class has custom  equality implementation the Moq doesnt work. Any idea on that please?

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code snippet and created empty classes to make it compile. It works as expected. Try it please and let me know what was the result.

Here is the code:

```
using Moq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stateConverter = new Mock<StateConverter>();

        var solution = new Mock<Solution>();
        var state = new Mock<State>();

        var neightbourSolution1 = new Mock<Solution>();
        var neighbourState1 = new Mock<State>();
        var neightbourSolution2 = new Mock<Solution>();
        var neighbourState2 = new Mock<State>();

        stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(neightbourSolution1.Object, It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState1.Object);
        stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(neightbourSolution2.Object, It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState2.Object);

        var state1 = stateConverter.Object.FromSolution(neightbourSolution1.Object, state.Object);
        var state2 = stateConverter.Object.FromSolution(neightbourSolution2.Object, state.Object);
    }
}

public class State{}

public class Solution{}

public abstract class StateConverter
{
    public abstract State FromSolution(Solution p0, State isAny);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your help. I have use your suggestion and it works fine. Then i have implement Equality member then its cause problem as above. Any idea how to fix it please? Do i have mock equality as well?

Comment: public class Solution{
          private String[] _strings;

        protected bool Equals(Solution other)
        {
            return Equals(_strings, other._strings);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Solution) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (_strings != null ? _strings.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }

Comment: Sorry comment did not allow too long text:-(

Answer (score 0):

One of the habits I've got into with Moq is to use the full It.Is(o => o == object) syntax to avoid any issues when the setup could be ambiguous or implicit. It could be that Moq is simply taking the object in the setup and overriding any others it already had there.

```
stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(neightbourSolution1.Object, It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState1.Object);
stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(neightbourSolution2.Object, It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState2.Object);
```

Would then look like

```
stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(It.Is<Solution>(solution => solution == neightbourSolution1.Object), It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState1.Object);
stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(It.Is<Solution>(solution => solution == neightbourSolution2.Object), It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState2.Object);
```

I'm not too sure if this would solve your issue as the implicitness is pretty damn clear. :/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried that however it didnt work. I have found the cause but still not sure how to overcome this. If my solution has customer equality implementation then this happen

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
[Test]
public void ClimbOnceTwoNeighbour_Sample()
{
    stateConverter = new Mock<StateConverter>();

    solution = new Mock<Solution>();
    state = new Mock<State>();

    var neightbourSolution1 = new Mock<Solution>();
    var neighbourState1 = new Mock<State>();
    var neightbourSolution2 = new Mock<Solution>();
    var neighbourState2 = new Mock<State>();

    stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(neightbourSolution1.Object, It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState1.Object);
    var state1 = stateConverter.Object.FromSolution(neightbourSolution1.Object, state.Object);//return null ????


    stateConverter.Setup(x => x.FromSolution(neightbourSolution2.Object, It.IsAny<State>())).Returns(neighbourState2.Object);
    var state2 = stateConverter.Object.FromSolution(neightbourSolution2.Object, state.Object);//return neighbourState2.Object)


    Assert.AreEqual(neighbourState2.Object, state2);//pass test here
    Assert.AreEqual(neighbourState1.Object, state1);//fail here due to null is returned from previous statement

}
```

I think that this way, when you assing to your state1 the result of the first return, you can use Setup again and add the result to state2 ;)